# Em C# é possível usar um alias local para classe ou namespace?

Tags: c#, classes, característica-linguagem, namespace

Em linguagens como Python ou PHP é possível utilizar um alias local para  classes ou *namespaces*.

Exemplo PHP:

```
 use Vendor\Package\ClassName as C;
 use Vendor\Package as P;

 $class = new C;

 $class = new P\ClassName;
```

Exemplo Python:

```
from json import dump as d

d({"name": "value"})
```

Chamo as operações acima de "alias local", pois somente naquele *script* é que aquela classe ou *namespace* terá o alias definido. Ou seja, não é acessível em outros *scripts*.

Em C# é possível definir um alias local, como se faz em PHP e em Python?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

É possível usar vários tipos de aliases em C#. Pode usar um simples:

```
using WF = System.Windows.Forms; //só fez o alias do namespace
```

Uso:

```
var botao = new WF.Button();
```

Isso pode ser mais útil quando há ambiguidade. Porque no fundo quando não há, esse `WF` nem seria necessário. Então pra que criar um alias para usar em um lugar que nem precisaria ter nada?

Alguns até gostam de ser mais explícitos para evitar ambiguidade de leitura, mas ser explícito pode deixar o código longo. Como pode haver ambiguidade futura, o programador já coloca lá o nome completo. Como esses nomes podem ser muitos longos essa forma facilita um pouco a digitação e espaço de leitura.

Um exemplo melhor talvez seja em um lugar que precisa usar um `Stream` específico e no mesmo código usar um outro que tem os mesmos elementos (mesmos tipos) com mesmos nomes. Se não colocar o qualificador completo, o compilador recusa por motivos óbvios. Colocar o qualificador completo fica muito longo, você cria um alias mais curto.

O ideal é usar com cautela, não pode ficar brincando com os nomes por gosto, tem que ser uma forma de resolver um problema, não causar outro.

Ou pode fazer algo mais complexo:

```
using Dict = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, List<string>>;
```

Uso:

```
var dict = new Dict { "palavra", new List<string> { "definição1", "definicão2" },  "palavra2", new List<string> { "definição1", "definicão2" } };
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/Alias.cs).

Aqui já é mais interessante porque o alias não é do `namespace` e sim do tipo, e um bem complexo que seria chato usar várias vezes no código, desta forma pode se referir a ele de forma mais simples sem acrescentar nada no código, como ocorreu com o `WF` acima.

Alguns vão dizer que assim é mais [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101), discordo que isso seja exatamente DRY, apenas evita repetição.

Outro exemplo legal da [resposta do Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/505268/221800).

```
namespace RealCode {
    //using Foo; // can't use this - it breaks DoSomething
    using Handy = Foo.Handy;
    using Bar;
    static class Program {
        static void Main() {
            Handy h = new Handy(); // prove available
            string test = "abc";            
            test.DoSomething(); // prove available
        }
    }
}
namespace Foo {
    static class TypeOne {
        public static void DoSomething(this string value) { }
    }
    class Handy {}
}
namespace Bar {
    static class TypeTwo {
        public static void DoSomething(this string value) { }
    }
}
```

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Comment: Galerinha do C# rápida para responder :)

Comment: A ideia inicial era "usar para diminuir digitação", mas sei que isso é coisa de preguiçoso.

Comment: Como eu falei na resposta, pra *namespaces* na verdade ocorre o oposto, na maioria dos casos, não fazer alias é o normal e mais curta forma.

Answer (score 5):

Sim, é possível definir *alias* para namespaces e classes através da [diretiva `using`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx).

```
using Foo = System.Globalization.CultureInfo; // Alias para a classe `CultureInfo`
using Bar = System.Globalization; // Alias para a namespace `System.Globalization`
```

Answer (score 3):

Em `C#` é possível definir um [NameSpace alias](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d(VS.80).aspx), como pode ser visto na documentação.

Para usar, basta colocar `using nomeAlias = NameSpace.Completo`.

Um exemplo do seu uso seria:

```
using teste = System;
 
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  public class Program
  {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      teste.Console.WriteLine("teste Alias");
    }
  }
}
```

Onde `teste` é um alias para `System`.

Veja o exemplo no [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BHIp0t).

#### E quando devo utilizar?

Não existe uma "regra" para utilização, mas ele é utilizado quando existe algum conflito de `NameSpaces` (ambiguidade) ou quando o `NameSpace` está oculto em outra entidade.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters É que esse não é o exemplo que quero adicionar, mas o `DotNetFiddle` está dando pau. kkk

Answer (score 1):

Sim.

Escreve o nome do apelido (`Linq`) e iguale ao `namespace` (`System.Linq`) para criação do apelido

```
using Linq = System.Linq;
```

*Codificando:*

```
Linq.IQueryable<>
Linq.Enumerable
```

***Links:***

- [9.3.1 Using alias directives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664765(v=vs.71).aspx)
- [Como usar o alias de namespace global (Guia de Programação em C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx)
- http://www.dotnetperls.com/using-alias