# Indisponibilidade da Classe Image do System.Drawing

Tags: .net, framework

Não tá disponível essa classe.

```
System.Drawing.Image;
```

Utilizo o Vs 2013 e NetFramework 4.5.2 e a dll system.drawing v.4.0

Já adicionei as referências e já inclusive importei uma dll "nova" e não fica disponível.

Só declarando System.Drawing já funciona.

Comment: Qual o tipo do projeto? O que você está tentando fazer com o código mostrado acima? Declarar uma variável ou fazer um import (using)?

Comment: @jbueno using estava tentando.

Answer (score 1):

Se você quer utilizar esta classe (Image) no *namespace*, terá que definir um **Alias** para ela.

Após isso, poderá fazer o seguinte:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using meuAlias = System.Drawing.Image;

namespace Imagem {
    public partial class TesteImagem : Form {
        public TesteImagem() {
            //Construtor
        }

        public void MeuMetodo() {
            //Acessando diretamente a classe com o caminho completo
            var imagem1 = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("c:\teste.bmp");

            //Usando o Alias criado no Namespace
            var imagem2 = meuAlias.FromFile("c:\teste.jpg");
        }
    }
}
```

Lembrando que os *namespace* servem para simplificar a codificação, não se precisa deles caso sempre usar os nomes completos.
Veja, podemos acessar diretamente esse método `Range`, que está na classe `Enumerable`, que por sua vez, está no *namespace Linq*:

```
var teste = System.Linq.Enumerable.Range(0, 10);
```

**Leituras recomendadas**
[Em C# é possível usar um alias local para classe ou namespace?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/134944/46243)

[Como usar o alias de namespace global](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)